# How can I combine these 2 SQL Queries into one

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am having some trouble figuring out how to combine these 2 queries.

```
$get_id = $psk->goqueryvalue("SELECT `categoryid` FROM `products` WHERE `seo_title` = '{$url_title}'");

$get_category = $psk->goqueryvalue("SELECT `title` FROM `categories` WHERE `id` = '{$get_id}'");
```

($psk->goqueryvalue just returns a single value.)

Thanks

Comment: is there any relation ( Foreign key reference )between your tables `products` and `categories`??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT c.title # also c.id if you need it
FROM categories c, products p 
WHERE c.id = p.categoryid 
AND p.seo_title = '{$url_title}'
```

Comment: Worked great thanks. I think the c.id = p.categoryid bit confused me as I was trying a similar query early but didn't think it would work.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like

```
    SELECT `categoryid`, `title` FROM `products` 
    LEFT JOIN `categories` ON `products`.`categoryid` = `categories`.`id` 
    WHERE `products`.`seo_title` = '{$url_title}'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like

```
$get_category = $psk->goqueryvalue("SELECT `title` FROM `categories` WHERE `id` = (SELECT `categoryid` FROM `products` WHERE `seo_title` = '{$url_title}'");
```

OR

```
$get_category = $psk->goqueryvalue("SELECT `title` FROM `categories` INNER JOIN `products` ON  
`categories.id` = `products.categoryid` WHERE `seo_title` = '{$url_title}'");
```